# fancy box resize image

Tags: jquery, resize, fancybox

```
<li><a  href="image-files/chinese-garden-cs01.jpg">
<img alt="Chinese Garden" src="image-files/chinese-garden-cs01.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
<p> Daphnie had a piece of waste ground  </p></a></li>
```

consider the following item in a list. when i click on the item the image opens in a fancy box,
however its size remains the same. i want to increase the size of the image. to something like 600px i have tried using the following code, but nothing works

```
 'autoDimension': false,
  'width': 600,
  'height': 600
```

---

```
 'autoScale': false,
  'width': 600,
  'height': 600
```

any Ideas ..........

the link is : http://note-builder.com/gig/new%20proline/case-studies.php

HERE IS A WORKING Fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/vwake/GZhLy/6/

http://jsfiddle.net/vwake/GZhLy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onStart` property of fancybox. It takes a callback which will be executed when the fancybox starts loading. Along with this you should make sure the fancybox dimensions are good enough to incorporate the image with height/width 600. Try this

```
        onStart: function(){
            $(“img”).attr({
                width : 600,
            }).removeAttr(‘height’);
        },
```

Comment: tried that.. had some sntax issues cleared it.. but still no go
 http://note-builder.com/gig/new%20proline/case-studies.php